# Can I install a firewall interface without `menu`?

Tags: networking, firewall

I need an interface for ufw (uncomplicated firewall) that does not depend on "menu", which is outdated and messing with software updates/installations. I don't mind building from source but prefer a deb.

Comment: the control goes ipchains to ufw to whatever... the head of the firewall controllers is ultimately ipchains/iptables. saying i want a gui with less dependencies is kind of......slow.  either you want the dependencies or you want to use the command line.  make a decision

Comment: I don't quite get the point of your comment. It's neither helpful nor making any sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[I found a deb](http://ubuntin.wordpress.com/2010/11/26/gufw-firewalls-have-never-been-easier/) on planet ubuntu that doesn't require menu :D! Solved. It is for a newer version of gufw.

Fortunately [gufw](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gufw) [image: Install gufw] no longer requires menu.

Answer (score 3):

Firestarter, fireshark, fwbuilder, shorewall are some of the firewall builders available. firestarter is gtk based, and might be the lightest of these. They are available through Synaptic Package Manager if not in Software Center. There is also the option of building iptables using ufw without the gui. Information about firestarter is available at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firestarter . For a bit of information on firewalls and the GUI's to build them, see https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/C/firewall.html .

Comment: Thanks for the info. I checked out firestarter, but it requires installation of "menu" and that's a big minus, as the menu package slows down software installation and is outdated (even obsolete).

Answer (score -2):

Try Comodo firewall. Comodo's firewall claims to provide protection from viruses, malware, and hackers.

Comment: ... please can you expand your answer explaining where to download, compile, install and use this.  I've removed the "spam" statements.